# MysqlWOrkBench Keep failing on Mac M2 ventura

Tags: mysql-workbench, macos-ventura

Mysql workbench keeps failing on mac m2 laptop and tried running the error log on chatgpt and got that the app is trying to access a restricted action. I want to use mysqlworkbench because it is a requirement. Any suggested fix ?

i want to fix the issue so that i can use it to run query and it is a requirement at work

error report sent to apple

````
-------------------------------------

Process:               MySQLWorkbench [9102]
Path:                  /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/MySQLWorkbench
Identifier:            com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench
Version:               8.0.32.CE (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Translated)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2023-03-09 15:06:27.4805 +0300
OS Version:            macOS 13.2.1 (22D68)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        F94BC9DD-B229-2F3A-5E70-CCF4D5D98EFE

Sleep/Wake UUID:       66BDF279-F100-4B57-B69F-C507DF2EDCE7

Time Awake Since Boot: 22000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       3535 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 4 Illegal instruction: 4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [9102]

Application Specific Backtrace 0:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80fa83cb3 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff80f5d210a objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80fb1abbe -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80f9eeab0 ___forwarding___ + 1324
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80f9ee4f8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   WBExtras                            0x000000010bf711a1 -[MResultsetViewer tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:] + 393
6   AppKit                              0x00007ff812de286e -[NSTableView _delegateWillDisplayCell:forColumn:row:] + 104
7   AppKit                              0x00007ff812d276d3 -[NSTableView preparedCellAtColumn:row:] + 1835
8   MySQLWorkbench                      0x0000000102f19a98 -[MGridView preparedCellAtColumn:row:] + 54
9   AppKit                              0x00007ff812d26e9d -[NSTableView _drawContentsAtRow:column:withCellFrame:] + 42
10  AppKit                              0x00007ff812d26b1d -[NSTableView drawRow:clipRect:] + 1638
11  AppKit                              0x00007ff812d26198 -[NSTableView drawRowIndexes:clipRect:] + 707
12  AppKit                              0x00007ff812cb1d09 -[NSTableView drawRect:] + 1670
13  AppKit                              0x00007ff812be4194 _NSViewDrawRect + 121
14  AppKit                              0x00007ff8133c93c3 -[NSView _recursive:displayRectIgnoringOpacity:inContext:stopAtLayerBackedViews:] + 1810
15  AppKit                              0x00007ff812be38c0 -[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) _drawViewBackingLayer:inContext:drawingHandler:] + 753
16  AppKit                              0x00007ff812cd9e34 -[_NSBackingLayerContents drawLayer:inContext:] + 152
17  AppKit                              0x00007ff812cd9b8c -[_NSTiledLayer drawTile:inContext:] + 565
18  AppKit                              0x00007ff812cd98de -[_NSTiledLayerContents drawLayer:inContext:] + 210
19  QuartzCore                          0x00007ff817a1db59 CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 254
20  QuartzCore                          0x00007ff817a813c1 ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 53
21  QuartzCore                          0x00007ff817a1cd66 -[CALayer _display] + 2275
22  AppKit                              0x00007ff812cd97e8 -[NSTileLayer display] + 60
23  AppKit                              0x00007ff812cd80a4 -[_NSTiledLayerContents update:shouldCallPrepareContent:] + 3567
24  AppKit                              0x00007ff812cd70b1 -[_NSTiledLayer display] + 334
25  QuartzCore                          0x00007ff817a1bd08 _ZN2CA5Layer17display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 900
26  QuartzCore                          0x00007ff817b956c6 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionEdPd + 648
27  QuartzCore                          0x00007ff8179fcb35 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 725
28  AppKit                              0x00007ff812bf49bf __62+[CATransaction(NSCATransaction) NS_setFlushesWithDisplayLink]_block_invoke + 285
29  AppKit                              0x00007ff81340c767 ___NSRunLoopObserverCreateWithHandler_block_invoke + 41
30  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80fa0b3e1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
31  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80fa0b309 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 482
32  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80fa0a866 __CFRunLoopRun + 877
33  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80fa09e7f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
34  HIToolbox                           0x00007ff81989c766 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
35  HIToolbox                           0x00007ff81989c576 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 679
36  HIToolbox                           0x00007ff81989c2b3 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 70
37  AppKit                              0x00007ff812a952f3 _DPSNextEvent + 909
38  AppKit                              0x00007ff812a94174 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1219
39  AppKit                              0x00007ff812a867b7 -[NSApplication run] + 586
40  AppKit                              0x00007ff812a5a7f7 NSApplicationMain + 817
41  dyld                                0x000000020336e310 start + 2432


Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   AppKit                              0x7ff812dfdc66 -[NSApplication _crashOnException:] + 287
1   AppKit                              0x7ff812bf4bfb __62+[CATransaction(NSCATransaction) NS_setFlushesWithDisplayLink]_block_invoke + 857
2   AppKit                              0x7ff81340c767 ___NSRunLoopObserverCreateWithHandler_block_invoke + 41
3   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff80fa0b3e1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
4   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff80fa0b309 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 482
5   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff80fa0a866 __CFRunLoopRun + 877
6   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff80fa09e7f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
7   HIToolbox                           0x7ff81989c766 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
8   HIToolbox                           0x7ff81989c576 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 679
9   HIToolbox                           0x7ff81989c2b3 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 70
10  AppKit                              0x7ff812a952f3 _DPSNextEvent + 909
11  AppKit                              0x7ff812a94174 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) ```
````

Comment: Please raise this issue with mysql as this is a bug with a desktop application, not a programming related question!

Comment: Is writing sql query not programming and it an issue that needs a work around. if you dont have answer dont answer

Comment: Writing an sql query is programming. However, your question is not about writing an sql query, is it?

Answer (score 2):

### **MySQLWorkBench Fix for Mac M2 MacOs Ventura**

Uninstall current version and remove data cached by the app

Downgrade to version 8.0.31.

Comment: Not working even I down graded to 8.0.31 ... You still using without any issue until now?